Maggots (?) in Katoomba Red Lentils
I cooked split red lentils and moong dhal both Katoomba brand. Both won't expire till Aug 2026. I did not add any spices, nothing!.
After boiling for about 45mins, I noticed black specks attached to white bits floating to the top. It's very unusual as I've cooked these before and never seen black specks at all.
I scooped out some on a glass bowl. Like to know if others have encountered the same. They look like maggots



Cooked Moong Dhal separately,  was ok, looks like from Lentils
Separated the black bits from the floating bits, seemed  hard . 
I also soaked some of the lentils after about 18hrs see pic 
Also cooked some from a freshly opened pack, yielded same result
Also did a search on google on lentil anatomy to try and understand where the black bits are from. Could someone shed some light?


I don’t know if those are specifically maggots, but it does look like some sort of insect got into one of your ingredients.
If you have any remaining, you might want to put them into a freezer or dispose of them (or cook it immediately if you’re willing to deal with the current level), to hopefully prevent it from contaminating other stuff in your pantry.
You may also want to mention it to whatever store you got them from.  Some will offer a refund, but they also need to deal with it before they have cross-contamination, too.

Probably pantry moths - they love dry goods like lentils. Definitely tell the store; if they don't seem to care, either shop elsewhere, or if that's not a possibility, freeze everything you buy from them (lentils, pasta, flour, corn meal, etc.) for a week. You'll also need to deal with your current infestation - search this site for various questions and answers on the subject.

Could also be carpet beetle larvae - if they are covered in longish hairs, it'll be carpet beetles. These might come from the shop or your house, pretty common world-wide.

I separated the black bits and they feel like a seed, hard. See pics

I don’t know if that’s maybe some sort of insect cocoon (as it looks like the worm was coming out of something similar), or maybe small rocks or other debris that wasn’t sorted out.  I don’t know if there’s a a better site to ask for identification… maybe biology or gardening?
